# JQuery - Próxima div quando clicar em um link

Tags: jquery

Tenho 2 divs e quando clico dentro de um link dentro da 1ª div preciso pegar o valor da 2ª div, como faço isso?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="vei">
    <span class="download"><a target="_blank" href='teste2.php'>download</a></span>
</div>
<div class="titulo"><a target="_blank" href='teste.php'>Teste</a></div>
```

**JS (tentei isso mas não deu certo):**

```
$( ".download a" ).click(function(e){
    $( ".download a" ).html($( ".titulo a" ).text(););
});
```

O "a" tem que virar "Teste" e não mais "download"!

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_traversing.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
$(".download a").click(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).closest('.vei').next('.titulo').find('a').text();
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ktu6ehsf/1/

A ideia é subir no DOM com [`.closest('.vei')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), procurar o proximo elemento com [`.next('.titulo')`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) e depois descer dentro desse elemento à procura de [`.find('a')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Answer (score 1):

Você colocou 2 ;(ponto e virgula)

Substitua

```
$( ".download a" ).click(function(e){
    $( ".download a" ).html($( ".titulo a" ).text(););
});
```

Por

```
$( ".download a" ).click(function(e){
    $( ".download a" ).html($( ".titulo a" ).text());
    return false;
});
```